# jQuery fadeOut and then submit()

Tags: jquery, submit, fadeout

This code does not work.
Fade Out works fine, but form is not submitted.
What is wrong?

```
<div id="main_div">
 <form action="#" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="name"><br>
  <input type="password" name="pass"><br>
  <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login">
 </form>
</div>

$("form").submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $("#main_div").fadeOut(1000, function() {
    $("form").submit();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("form").submit();` is triggering your handler again, causing an infinite loop.

Try this instead:

`$('form').off('submit', handler).submit();`.

Demo:

```js
$('form').on('submit', function handler(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#main_div').fadeOut(1000, function() {
    $('form').off('submit', handler).submit();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main_div">
 <form action="https://en.wikipedia.org" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="name"><br>
  <input type="password" name="pass"><br>
  <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login">
 </form>
</div>
```

Note: using a `form` selector seems like a bad idea, and `$(this)` should be preferred within event handlers in such cases.